# Show content depending on dy and time

Tags: javascript

I was looking for answers here but couldnt fin. Im pretty unexperienced with Javascript. Where is my error. I cant get this script to work. It's supposed to show specific content on the website depending of the day of the week and the time of the day.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();
var time = new Date().getTime();



let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

days.forEach((day,index)=>{
    // Check if the index of day value is equal to the returned value of getDay()
if(index == new Date().getDay()){
    if (time >= start.setHours(06,00) && time =< end.setHours(09,59)) {
    let show = "Show1";
    $(".open").show();
    $(".closed").hide();
}
else {
    $(".open").hide();
    $(".closed").show();

}
if (time >= start.setHours(10,00) && time =< end.setHours(11,59)) {
    let show = "Show2";
    $(".open").show();
    $(".closed").hide();
}
else {
    $(".open").hide();
    $(".closed").show();

}
if (time >= start.setHours(12,00) && time =< end.setHours(13,59)) {
    let show = "Show3";
    $(".open").show();
    $(".closed").hide();
}
else {
    $(".open").hide();
    $(".closed").show();
)
}}};
```

I want  this script set conditions which i can use in  to display a specific information which show is actually on.

These are the  containers:

```
  <div class="open">Christian Music Nonstop</div>
  <div class="closed">Nope</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your issues are in the actual if statement, you're using =< instead of <=, also you're setting the hours within the loop?

I can't really tell without seeing the rest of your code but that seems wrong, but I don't know the rest of your code, you could try this though

```
 var time = new Date().getHours();

    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

   
    if(days[new Date().getDay()]) {
        if (time >= 6 && time <= 9) {
            $(".open").show();
            $(".closed").hide();
        } else if (time >= 10 && time <= 11) {
            $(".open").show();
            $(".closed").hide();
        } else if (time >= 12 && time <= 13) {
            $(".open").show();
            $(".closed").hide();
        } else {
            $(".open").hide();
            $(".closed").show();
        }
    }
```

If that doesn't work then just change the comparators in your code

Comment: It works so far, only: How do I add either a URL thats been taken over by the DIV? Could I do that with a class? or id? Which changes the status if one of the Ifs or elses come true?

Comment: Yes I am setting the hours in the loops. The Idea is to check for each day and display from monday to sunday depending on the hour different Picture or urls....

Comment: var link = $("#The ID of whatever you want to change"); / then in your loop  link.attr("href", "whatever.html");